# Problem with applying material - Donut Tutorial part 7, level 1

Tags: materials

I split my screen into two by using the vertical split function and when I merged the two screens the materials/colors on my mesh’ disappeared and I can’t get them back. When I merged the two screens I did the mistake by dragging the screen without color onto the one without color.

I have restarted Blender afterwards in hopes that I would be able to apply materials to the mesh - but without any luck.

Also I can see I have 4 materials for the plane and have tried to delete it, but I don’t know how.

Do any one know how I can fix it?
[image]

Comment: you are in Solid mode (second of the 4 spheres on the top right of your 3D view), switch to another viewport shading mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your problem ocurs because you are in *Solid View Mode* and not *Material View Mode*.

To change view mode go to the top rigth corner of the *Viewport* with the diferent textured balls (See the image bellow)
To see your materials change it to the third mode.

Zoom in into *View Mode* buttons:

[image: Zoom in into View Mode buttons]

*Material View Mode:*

[image: Material View Mode]

*Object View Mode:*

[image: Material View Mode]

---

### And to delete materials:

Go to the *Outliner* (the place on the rigth side where it shows your objects, cameras, and ligths) and change the mode from *View Layer* to *Blender File*

[image: Outliner]

Then navigate to the Materials folder and delete the unwanted materials (Here you can't delete <kbd>X</kbd> like with objects, so rigth click and choose delete).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Solved my problem :)

Answer (score 7):

You have the viewport set to display in Solid mode (1).
Click the icon to the right (2 - Material Preview) to show you colours/materials.
[image]

It's not clear what you mean by your second question. Maybe post a new question with an image showing the issue.